# Postgres to-json converts a composite type into empty structure

Tags: json, postgresql, to-json

in the following code example postgresql (9.4) is supposed to transform a local variable of a composite type into a json string. apparently postgresql handle a variable with null value different than a null-value cast to the same type.

in my application i have nested composite types and would like to retrieve null when a variable of a composite type has null as a value.

i hope on of you guys can help me out here.

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (
    id SMALLINT,
    name TEXT
);

DO $$
DECLARE
    l_var mytype;
BEGIN
    l_var := NULL;
    RAISE INFO '%',to_json(NULL::mytype);
    RAISE INFO '%',to_json(l_var) ;
END $$; 

--Output
INFO:  <NULL>
INFO:  {"id":null,"name":null}
```

Comment: Huh, so in PL/PgSQL assigning `NULL` to a record var is different to passing a `NULL` record var to a function. I would not have guessed that. What an odd wart.

Comment: l_var is not record var, but row var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, PostgreSQL distinguish between ROW with empty fields and NULL. A fix should not be hard - you should to use CASE expression:

```
postgres=# DO $$
DECLARE
    l_var mytype;
BEGIN
    l_var := NULL;
    RAISE INFO '%',to_json(NULL::mytype);
    RAISE INFO '%',to_json(CASE WHEN l_var IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE l_var END) ;
END $$; 
INFO:  <NULL>
INFO:  <NULL>
DO
```

Comment: Well, more workaround than fix. If I saw that in someone's code without an explanatory comment I'd be doing some serious "WTF?".

Comment: @CraigRinger - it is result of difference between RECORD and ROW types in Postgres. ROW types has structure every time, so it cannot be scalar NULL. Some years ago this question was opened, and the result was - The ANSI SQL requires this behave, if I remember wall.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly pavels solution doesn't work for me, because it's used in another type and i cant apply the proposed  case-structure then.

But after talking to the backend devlopers, ist better for them to always receive a full json structure even tho the fields have no value. So from the symantic Point of view, postgres works fine.

Comment: There is another possibility in prepared PostgreSQL 9.5. You can use a json_strip_nulls function, that reduce json `{"id":null,"name":null}` to `{}`